# How do I randomly select a dropdown item from a list? (angular 5)

Tags: angular

I have a list like this...

```
export const inventory=
[
'coffee'
'tea'
'wine'
'beer'
'sake'
....
];
```

In the html I am looping through to create dropdown a fix amount of times.

```
 <div *ngFor="let number of numbers; let i = index" >
    <select class="roles-select" [(ngModel)]="number.selectedItem" (change)="selected($event)" >
      <option *ngFor="let inv of inventoryList; let x = index" [ngValue]="inv">{{inv}} 
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

in my component I have this and it is working.

```
  public numbers = [];
  public selectedItem;
 public inventoryList = inventory;
  constructor() {
    this.numbers = Array(3).fill(0).map((x , i) => i);
   }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);  // generate random default in the list?
  }

  selected(value: any) {
      console.log('selected dropdown: ' + value.target.name + value.target.value);
  }
```

What I want is to generate 3 different items randomly for the dropdown as default....but I am not sure how it can be done.

Comment: yes number is array [] I just filled it with 0s and loop through them to create number of dropdowns. it is like (for int i=0; i < 3 ; i++) { create dropdowns }

Comment: No, because if i switch them then when I select a dropdown it changes for all 3 dropdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

export const inventory = ["coffee", "tea", "wine", "beer", "sake"];

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public numbers = [];
  public selectedItems = [];
  public inventoryList = inventory;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.numbers = Array(3).fill(0).map((x, i) => i);
    this.numbers.forEach(num => this.selectedItems.push(inventory[Math.floor(Math.random()*inventory.length)]));
  }

  selected(value: any) {
    console.log("selected dropdown: " + value.target.name + value.target.value);
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let number of numbers; let i = index">
    <select class="roles-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems[i]" (change)="selected($event)" >
    <option *ngFor="let inv of inventoryList; let x = index">{{inv}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbsiuj?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

I'd suggest using a Reactive Form for this though.

Answer (score 1):

do somethig like that:

```
  public numbers = [];
  inventoryList = ["coffee", "tea", "wine", "beer", "sake"];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.numbers = Array(3)
      .fill(0)
      .map((x, i) => {
        return { value: Math.floor(Math.random() * this.inventoryList.length) };
      });
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let number of numbers; let i = index" >
   {{number | json}}
    <select class="roles-select" [(ngModel)]="number.value" (change)="selected($event)" >
      <option *ngFor="let inv of inventoryList; let x = index" [ngValue]="x">{{inv}} 
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-87iyy6